# AppCenter Crashes not visible

Tags: ios, visual-studio-app-center

Hi We have implemented Appcenter Sdk in iOS App. But only crash visible on dashboard which we are forcing with default method MSCrashes.generateTestCrash().Rest of the crashes taking place in app are not visible

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most relevant answer but while uploading your app to appstore /test flight make sure you have ticked this , without it being ticked your crashes wont be available .

[image]

Comment: We are in dev phase for this feature . Checking in dev environment as such not uploaded the build for the same in appcenter. Just integrate the sdk and implment the required functions as per doc

Answer (score 0):

make sure your app is not connected to debugger and that there are no **Unsymbolicated** crashes on the portal. Also, pls include the verbose logs from 2 app launches (before and after the crash).